# how i can use if else into sum - mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i could not find the correct query of sql, how i can use if else statement in sum?? i want add `sum(if(noresult),0,number)` if there is no any result. but it doesnt work.

```
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  
                COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS bal_total 
            FROM alinanbaliklar 
            WHERE user_id = 1  
            GROUP BY user_id )balik
INNER JOIN ( SELECT 
                 COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS dom_total 
            FROM alinandomuzlar 
            WHERE user_id = 1  
            GROUP BY user_id )domuz
INNER JOIN ( SELECT   
                  COUNT(*),SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS seb_total 
             FROM alinanmeyvesebzeler 
             WHERE user_id = 1 
             GROUP BY user_id )sebze
INNER JOIN ( SELECT  
                 COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS ag_total 
            FROM alinanagaclar 
            WHERE user_id = 1 
            GROUP BY user_id )agac
```

Comment: this is not what i want.

Comment: You can't always get what you want , but you just might find you get what you need.

Comment: What number the sum or the count they are bith numbers, you should be more specific, what you are looking for

Comment: if there is result sum should return number if not then should return 0. how i can do it?

Comment: I noticed that you're using `INNER JOIN` and you don't follow that with an `ON` clause. Is the query even returning any result? Or do you receive an error message?

Comment: actually i just want correct sql query, i dont have any error when i use it, it's about to correct but somethings not enough, lemme give you an example. if there is no any result i want sum(number = 0), if there is result i want sum(number).

Answer (score -1):

You are only selecting one row.  So, dispense with the `GROUP BY` and use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS bal_total 
      FROM alinanbaliklar 
      WHERE user_id = 1  
     ) balik CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS dom_total 
      FROM alinandomuzlar 
      WHERE user_id = 1  
     ) domuz CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT   COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS seb_total 
      FROM alinanmeyvesebzeler 
      WHERE user_id = 1 
     ) sebze CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(cekilen_tutar)  AS ag_total 
      FROM alinanagaclar 
      WHERE user_id = 1 
     ) agac
```

Comment: nope it's correct query but not enough for me so that when no result it returns nothing. i just want  if there is no any result i want sum(number = 0), if there is result i want sum(number).